# Testing Functions with the same name in GO

Tags: go

In go it is possible to write functions that are specific to structs.

```
type one struct{}

func (o *one) fly() {}
```

My questions is how can you test a function if there are two functions with the same name but point to different structs.

```
type one struct{}

func (o *one) fly() {}

type two struct{}

func (t *two) fly() {}
```

Since the formatting for GO tests is TestXxx (t *testing.T) {}
I'm unsure how I would be able to test each function separately. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TestXxx` is just a naming convention. `Xxx` may be anything you want, but `Test` (with `Benchmark` and `Example`) are required. So, declare 2 testing functions — `TestOneFly` and `TestTwoFly`, that's all. Or you can test both in `TestFly`, initializing both structs in one test.

Comment: Thanks I thought it had to line up exactly with the actual method name or it wouldn't run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the specific function using the dot operator on an instance of the struct.

```
aOne := one{}
aOne.fly() //Calls the first version

aTwo := two{}
aTwo.fly() //Calls the second version
```